# How I can attach a link to ListTile which opens up a link on Browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

```
ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.link,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text(
                'Body Mass Index Calculator',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
```

I am trying to make a link that opens website on browser directly.

Answer (score 1):

Using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) you do easily.

Here Example:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

//I assumed your link like below :
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');

      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.link,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 30,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'Body Mass Index Calculator',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
            throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
          }
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `url_launcher: ^6.1.0` The plugin introduces support for webOnlyWindowName property and few Other new apis like launchUrl, For web support now you longer have to depend on dart:html You can simply declare the below function

```
Future<void> launchLink(String url, {bool isNewTab = true}) async {
    await launchUrl(
        Uri.parse(url),
        webOnlyWindowName: isNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self',
    );
}
```

and use it like this

```
onTap:(){
    launchLink('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', isNewTab: true);
}
```